# Is a silent/mental bracha considered valid?

Tags: halacha, blessing, hearing

It appears to be the custom everywhere to say brachot out loud that others can hear.

However, I recall that Shimon Bar Yochai in the Gemara prescribes saying your brachot very quietly and in all humility (I have no idea what is the exact location). Bar Yochai had a more introverted approach to spiritual living, and personally I've found it more meaningful to say brachot silently than out loud.

So what are the sources saying on whether a silent/mental bracha is considered valid?

Comment: [Welcome to Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3886/a-beginner-s-guide-to-my-how-is-this-site-different-from-other-judaism-sites/3887#3887), Minim, and thanks for bringing your question here!

Comment: As mbloch details in his answer, there is a middle ground that you skipped in your question. You do not need to say them so that other people can hear, but you should/must say them. A prayer is you talking to G-d.

Answer (score 3):

The Rambam ([MT Brachot 1:7](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/927667/jewish/Berachot-Chapter-One.htm)) writes you should ideally hear yourself

> A person should recite all the blessings loud enough for him to hear
>   what he is saying. Nevertheless, a person who does not recite a
>   blessing out loud fulfills his obligation, whether he verbalizes the
>   blessing or merely recites it in his heart.

However R Binyomin Forst in his [Laws of B'rachos](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899062204.html) writes

> Most authorities reject the view that one can mentally recite a
>   *bracha* and fulfill one's obligation (SA [OC 206:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.206.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)). A *bracha* must be uttered by the movements of one's lips pronouncing each word
>   (but R Shlomo Zalman Auerbach allows lips pronunciation even if no
>   sound is emitted).
>
> There is considerable disagreement in the Mishna and Talmud ([Brachot 15a](https://www.sefaria.org/Berakhot.15a.6?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) and [Megila 19b](https://www.sefaria.org/Megillah.19b.7?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) as to
>   whether it is necessary for the *bracha* to be audible to the person
>   making the *bracha*. Though it is clearly desirable that the *bracha*
>   be recited in audible voice, the failure to do so does not invalidate
>   the *bracha* ([SA OC 206:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.206.3?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

As you see these sources do not mention that others need to hear you. Personally I would imagine one rationale for doing so is to allow others to say amen to your *bracha*.